# What is the probability that the difference between ,  is a multiple of 4?

Tags: probability, statistics

Randomly choose a pair {, } (with replacement) from the set of consecutive integers 6, 7, 8 . . . , 14. What is the probability that
the difference between ,  namely | − | is a multiple of 4? Recall || represents the absolute value of  so | − 3| = 3, |3| = 3

I got 4/27, but that is after plotting every single possibility and then highlighting the ones that matched the description (so ones where |a-b| = 4, 8 or 12. I think there is probably an easier way to do, this, but can anyone point me in the direction of how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Don't forget 0 is a multiple of 4

Answer (score 2):

We want the probability that $a \equiv b \pmod 4$.  The set has $3$ elements $x$ such that $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ and $2$ elements $y$ for such that $y \equiv z \pmod 4$ for $z = 0, 1, 3$.

There is a probability of $\frac 13$ that our first choice $x$ satisfies $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, in which case the probability of success is $\frac 13$.  There is a probability of $\frac 23$ that our first choice $x$ does *not* satisfy $x \equiv 2 \pmod 4$, in which case the probability of success is $\frac 29$.

Thus, the overall probability of success is $\frac 13 \cdot \frac 13 + \frac 23 \cdot \frac 29 = \frac{7}{27}$.  As noted in the comments, you have overlooked the $\frac 19$ probability that the two numbers selected are identical.

Answer (score 1):

Let $~A = \{6,10,14\}, ~B = \{7,8,9,11,12,13\} \implies~ :$

- $~A,B~$ are disjoint.
- $~A \cup B = \{6,7,\cdots,14\}.$
- If a number is selected at random from $~A \cup B,~$ the probability of the number being from set $~A~$ is $~\dfrac{1}{3}.~$

When a number is selected from set $~A,~$ the probability that a second number from $~A \cup B~$ will be satisfactory is $~\dfrac{3}{9}.$

When a number is selected from set $~B,~$ the probability that a second number from $~A \cup B~$ will be satisfactory is $~\dfrac{2}{9}.$

Therefore, the overall probability that the two numbers form a satisfactory pair is

$$\left[\frac{1}{3} \times \frac{3}{9}\right] + \left[\frac{2}{3} \times \frac{2}{9}\right] = \frac{7}{27}.$$